# Laravel - Tests on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, testing

I'm learning Laravel and Functional tests.
On laracast we have in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```

I can not test on mysql database because when I switch my `DB_CONNECTION` param to "mysql" I have error "`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database ':memory:'`".

When I don't use memory all tables are removed from my database:

My Test Class looks like that:

```
class ThreadsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_browse_threads()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/threads');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how can I test in memory with MySQL?
I can't find any information

Answer (score 2):

You can run with separete database

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
    <env name="DB_HOST" value="localhost"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
    <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="root" />
    <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You can't run MySQL as an in-memory database as you can with SQLite.

Comment: So how we can test on MySQL ? All tables are removed after run tests. What is correct way to testing on MySQL database ?

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed on your system?

Comment: Yes. Only MySQL  (XAMPP)

Comment: Create a separate database for your tests and add it to `phpunit.xml`. You can wrap your tests in transactions to rollback the changes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: I really don't get this, those phpunit tests for memory are created on purpose so that you don't mess up with mysql database....if the test works fine with :memory: sqllite why it wouldn't work with mysql? you don't need to run the same test twice.

Comment: An application written for MySQL doesn't always work with SQLite because of missing database features. Even if it does, testing with SQLite is not a replacement for testing with the production environment's DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the parameters

```
<php>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```

to

```
<php>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="your_test_instance"/>
</php>
```